# MVC3 binding for a json nested array

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, data-binding

I have a simple javascript array. it's declared like this:

```
coords = []
```

and everytime a user clicks on an image, I do something like this:

```
coords.push([x,y])
```

so I end up with something like this: (in javascript)

```
[[342,144],[477,99],[632,148],[529,162]]
```

but I don't know what to bind it to in the controller method... I've tried

```
List<List<int>>, int[][], int[,]
```

none of them seem to work. It only works when I use string.

This is the code I'm using to send it to the server:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/home/SaveCoords",
    data: { coords: JSON.stringify(coords) }
}).done(function (msg) {
    alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
});
```

And this is the code I use on the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveCoords(string coords)
{
    return Json("Hello", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Help?

Comment: Have you tried List<Tuple<int,int>>?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should set request content type to `application/json`, and change `data` accordingly.

This is the working example:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/home/SaveCoords",
        contentType : 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(coords)
    }).done(function (msg) {
        alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
    });
```

And server

```
    public ActionResult SaveCoords(int[][] coords)
    {
        return View();
    }
```